# Swift 2 NSUserDefaults read Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift2

i'm updating my app to Swift 2.. lots of errors uff.. anyway i'm trying to read a store array in NSuserDefaults, in swift 1 worked but now i get nil error with EXC_Breakdown. i don't know how to fix that...

this is how i read it:

```
 var DescriptionArray = save.objectForKey("NewsDescriptions")! as! NSArray
```

this i how i save it (Description is the array):

```
 var SaveDescription = save.setObject(Description, forKey: "NewsDescriptions")        
  save.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can store data into `NSUserDefault` in **Swift 2.0**. It is very similar to Objective-C concept, only different syntax.

**Initialize your `NSUserDefault` Variable:**

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
```

**Initialize what type of data to save:** In your case you used objectForKey, even though that should work, it's better to be more specific about your code.

```
var DescriptionArray = userDefaults.arrayForKey("NewsDescriptions")
```

**Save your data:**

```
userDefaults.setObject(Description, forKey: "NewsDescriptions")
```

Then you can `synchronize` to process the saving faster.

```
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: Just wondering where the usage of "codes" comes from since "code" is already plural WRT computer code.

Comment: @zaph Yeah, true. I guess I'm trying to be extra plurallllly, English is my 3rd language. lol give me a break.

Comment: OK, I understand, perhaps the use of "code" is an Americam-ism.

Comment: I was not making a reference to you, just wondering why I see "codes" often and I was wondering it is was a 2nd (or 3rd) or British English issue. I was not implying your usage was wrong.

Comment: @zaph Maybe, I mean I grew up in the US, but I have to speak other languages too, cause I'm surrounded by foreigners. But you're right, it should be `code` not `codes`.

Comment: I'm not sure "codes" is wrong. It is not like "data' which has a singular form "datum". There are instances were "codes" is used to refer to a number of items such as "I have all three missile launch codes".

Comment: @zaph True, I mean in my answer, it should be `code`, after all is one context.

Comment: i use Description cause is the array.. DescriptionArray doesn't exist.. i use it in another page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90165/discussion-between-marcoc-and-lgl).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with Swift 2:

```
    func saveArray(value: NSArray) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(value, forKey:"NewsDescriptions")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func readArray() -> NSArray {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("NewsDescriptions")!
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work at all since `arrayForKey` returns an `NSArray` and you try to return it directly as a `String`.